# How to take an array, and insert commas between each item?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to understand how to take an array like `[1,2,3,4,5]` and then between each index, add a `,` so the array becomes `[1, ', ', 2, ', ', 3, ', ', 4, ', ', 5]`

I know it sounds stupid but I'm having some issues with it.

Basically, I want to use something like `splice()` method, so that I can iterate over the array and each odd index, I can do `splice(index, 0, ', ')`.

Comment: Instead of trying to modify your array, return a new one - this will be easier to achieve.

Comment: A quick hack: `arr.join(',').split('');` - the JS engine will prefer them all being the same type (you'll have an array of strings) but it depends if you actually need mixed strings with number types or not.

Comment: For ES6, duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37128624/terse-way-to-intersperse-element-between-all-elements-in-javascript-array.

Comment: Thanks.  I am trying to follow JS interview questions, and one of them is to add some text to console.log.  I am able to answer that question correctly, so I am trying to challenge myself to add comma seperation (I know console log does NOT do this), but now I am failing my own challenge

Comment: _"Basically, I want to use something like splice() method, so that I can iterate over the array and each odd index, I can do splice(index, 0, ', ')"_ Start index at `1`, increment index passed to `.splice()` by `2`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `.reduce` method which accepts as parameter a `callback` function.

> The reduce() method applies a function against an accumulator and each
>   value of the array (from left-to-right) to reduce it to a single
>   value.

```js
var array=[1,2,3,4,5];
console.log(array.reduce(function(a,b){
    return a.concat(b).concat(",");
},[]).slice(0,-1));
```

Comment: Your solution shouldn't add a comma at the end of the result

Answer (score 3):

Use [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

1. Start with empty array
2. Push an element of `array` then push `', '`
3. At last remove last `', '` using [`.pop()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop)

```js
var array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

var array2 = array1.reduce(function(acc, val) {
  acc.push(val);
  acc.push(', ');
  return acc;
}, []);

array2.pop();

console.log(array2);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `reduce` to create a new array with the inserted values:

```js
function weaveArray(array, weaveValue) {
  const {length} = array;
  return array.reduce((result, value, i) => {
    if(i < length - 1) {
      result.push(value, weaveValue);
    } else {
      result.push(value);
    }
    return result;
  }, []);
}

console.log(
  weaveArray([1,2,3,4,5], ",")
);
```

Answer (score 1):

With just two methods:

**Edit**

If you want to save your commas use some regexp instead:

`var c = a.join(', ,  , ').split(/\s(?=,\s)/);`

```js
var a = [1,2,3,4,5];
var b = a.join(' , ').split(' ');
var c = a.join(', ,  , ').split(/\s(?=,\s)/);
console.log(b,c);
```

Comment: see my comment above - you may wish to mention that the types do not match the question.

Comment: your comment is bad because with `22`, `33` values it will  divide it into `2`, `2` etc.

Comment: I was only considering single numbers in the comment, but it doesn't change the information about types (specifically, JS engines _hate_ mixed type arrays - an array of all strings is much better).

Answer (score 1):

```js
console.log([1,2,3,4,5].reduce(function(acc, val, idx, list) {
  acc.push(val);
  if (idx < list.length - 1) {
    acc.push(',');

  }
  return acc;
}, []));
```

Answer (score 1):

Short solution using `Array.prototype.join()`, `Array.prototype.map()` and `String.prototype.match()` functions:

```js
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5],
    newArr = arr.join(',').match(/\w+|\W+/g).map(function(v){
        return (isNaN(v))? v : +v;  // considering numeric values
    });

console.log(newArr);
```

---

*You wanted `splice` approach?* Here it is:

```js
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5];
for (var i = 1; i < arr.length; i+=2) {
    arr.splice(i, 0, ',');
}

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variable at `.splice()` to increment index by `2`

```js
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5];
for (let i = 1, len = arr.length * 2; arr.length < len - 1; arr.splice(i, 0, ","), i += 2);
console.log(arr);
```